# PHP - Autoload only needed classes

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoloader

I have an autoloader that is placed as a php file above all other sub directories in my project.

What it does is it loads all possible classes at once for any specific server request.  After further thought I concluded I need to autoload only the required classes.

What do I need to do to avoid loading other classes not needed?
If I need to post the relevant code snippets of the class files in my subdirectories, I can.

```
<?php
    namespace autoloader;
    class autoloader
    {
        private $directoryName;
        
        public function __construct($directoryName)  
        {
            $this->directoryName = $directoryName;
        }  
        
        public function autoload()
        {
            foreach (glob("{$this->directoryName}/*.class.php") as $filename)
            {
                include_once $filename;           
            }
         
            foreach (glob("{$this->directoryName}/*.php") as $filename)
            {
                include_once $filename;           
            }
        }    
    }
    
    # nullify any existing autoloads
    spl_autoload_register(null, false);

    # instantiate the autoloader object
    $classes = [
        new autoloader('request'),
        new autoloader('config'),
        new autoloader('controllers'), 
        new autoloader('models'),
        new autoloader('data')
    ];

    # register the loader functions
    foreach ($classes as $class)
        spl_autoload_register(array($class, 'autoload'));
```

Comment: That code should not be named autloading - it does not. It loads everything. How it works is described in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload). Why not rely on the very well working composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All registered autoloader functions will be called when you try to instantiate a new class or until it finally loads the class or throws an error. The way you have it now, you're registering the same autoloader function again and again for each directory, and file.

What you'd want to do is something along the lines of this.

```php
namespace autoloader;

class autoloader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'autoload']);
    }

    public function autoload($classname)
    {
        if (! file_exists("{$classname}.class.php")) {
            return;
        }

        include_once "{$classname}.class.php";
    }    
}

new autoloader();
```

Every autoloader function gets the class FQCN passed into it, and from there you'll have to parse it and figure out if you can load the file where that class exists. For instance, if I do the following.

```php
use Some\Awesome\ClassFile;

$class = new ClassFile();
```

The autoloader we've registered will get the string `Some\Awesome\ClassFile` passed in as an argument, which we can then parse and see if we have a file for that class, if we don't we return out of the function and let the next registered autoloader function try and find the class.

You can read more about autoloaders in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), I also wrote a blog [post](https://devdojo.com/post/you-dont-necessarily-need-composer) about it like 2 months ago that might interest you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to refactor the code and remove the unnecessary load all functionality that I mistakenly thought would lazy load my classes on request.

Here is what I came up with:

Entry Point

```
<?php
    require_once 'enums.php';
    require_once 'api.class.php';

    spl_autoload('AutoLoader\AutoLoader');
    
    use App\API;

    class MyAPI extends API
    { 
        public function __construct($request){
            parent::__construct($request);
        }
    }
    
    $api = new MyAPI($_REQUEST); 
    echo $api->processRequest();
```

AutoLoader Implementation  (located under subdirectory Autoloader/Autoloader.php and inaccessible via browser by using .htaccess)

```
<?php
    namespace Autoloader;

    spl_autoload_register("AutoLoader\AutoLoader::ClassLoader");
    spl_autoload_register("AutoLoader\AutoLoader::RequestLoader");

    class Autoloader
    {
        public static function ClassLoader(String $fileName)
        {
            foreach ([".Class.php", ".php"] as $extension) 
                if (file_exists($fileName.$extension))
                    include $fileName.$extension;       
        } 
        
        public static function RequestLoader()
        {
            self::ClassLoader('Request');
        }
    }
```

Snippet for processRequest() (located in api.class.php - my request router)

```
public function processRequest() 
{
    $id1 = $this->requestObj->id1;
    $id2 = $this->requestObj->id2;
    $endpoint1 = $this->requestObj->endpoint1;
    $endpoint2 = $this->requestObj->endpoint2;
    $goto = $this->requestObj->goto;

    $isDestination = in_array($id1, ['first', 'prev', 'next', 'last']);
    $numSetEndpoints = (int)isset($endpoint1) + (int)isset($endpoint2);
    
    switch($numSetEndpoints)
    {
        case 0:
            if ($isDestination)
                return json_decode($this->_response("No Endpoint: ", $endpoint1));
            return json_decode($this->_response("No Endpoint: " . $endpoint2 ?? $endpoint));
        case 1:
            $className = $endpoint1.'Controller';
            break;
        case 2:
            $className = $endpoint2.'Controller';
            break;
    }

    $class = "\\Controllers\\$className";

    if (class_exists($class))
    {
        $method = strtolower($this->method); 
        if (method_exists($class, $method))
        {
            $response = (new $class($this->requestObj))->{$method}();
            
            if ($response['Succeeded'] == false)
            {
                return $response['Result'];
            }
            else if ($response['Succeeded'] == true)
            {    
                header("Content-Type: application/json");
                return $this->_response($response);
            }
            else if ($response['Result'])
            {
                header("Content-Type: text/html");
                return $this->_response($response);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really a learning experience to realize that the first implementation was totally unoptimized (had unnecessary code) and required a second look to refactor correctly.